# Increase the width of the bars while using jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using StackedBarChart in the jfreechart API to display no.records in a table which comes from the database. There are  82 tables which im putting on the domain axis and the no. of records in the Range axis. But the problem that I am facing is that because of so many tables in the domain axis, the width of the bar reduces.

Following is my code :

```
private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset)
    {
            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
             "Stacked Bar Chart", "Task Description", "No_Of_Records", dataset,
                        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

        CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot)chart.getPlot();
        CategoryAxis categoryaxis = categoryplot.getDomainAxis();
        categoryaxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelWidthRatio(100);
        categoryaxis.setLowerMargin(0.02D);
        categoryaxis.setUpperMargin(0.02D);

        NumberAxis numberaxis = (NumberAxis)categoryplot.getRangeAxis();
        numberaxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        numberaxis.setRange(0.0D, 1000D);
        BarRenderer barrenderer = (BarRenderer)categoryplot.getRenderer();
        barrenderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        GradientPaint gradientpaint = new GradientPaint(0.0F, 0.0F, Color.blue, 0.0F, 0.0F, new Color(0, 0, 64));
        barrenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gradientpaint);

        return chart;
}
```

I have tried using a

```
 setItemMargin();
 setMaxWidth();
 setMaximumBarWidth();
```

on the BarRenderer, but all in vain..

Any help is appreciated

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can experiment with [`setCategoryMargin()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html#setCategoryMargin%28double%29). Also, see how it looks when you right-click and zoom in.